# android destroy service

Tags: android, service, destroy

How can a user destroy a service outside of the app. I made an app that the user can never "Exit" because the main activity disables the "back" button, but now my service notification can't be removed (there will eventually be conditions on when it is shown, but not right now)! I know that android manages the memory when the app is in the background like that, but if I really wanted to close that service, how would this be done?

Comment: 'I made an app that the user can never "Exit" because the main activity disables the "back" button' ..  bad idea.

Comment: why, the android OS will kill it eventually when necessary. Look at the other questions here about how to clear android activity stacks, the consensus is that is also a "bad idea", so we've encountered a conundrum!

Comment: It's a bad idea because it deviates from how the user will expect the app to respond. Apps that you can't back out of? Confusing and annoying.

Comment: I actually agree, I use an app that is weird like that (it keeps switching between its other activities instead of backing out, even if its main screen was the only one loaded) and it kind of annoys me. But the home button remedies it.

Comment: @RD.: Preventing users from exiting your application via BACK is likely to earn you one-star ratings on the Market. Having a service stick around for no good reason is also likely to earn you one-star ratings on the Market. I humbly suggest that you revisit your approach to this app.

Comment: true.....  but lets keep the hypothetical gears going, is there any way to destroy a service (perhaps after a certain time period, or by request from a server, or the android system) without loading up/closing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Bindservice.The Service is stoped as the Bindservice.